# Change results of SQL in the query itself?

Tags: php, sql, group-by, rename

Hopefully I can translate what's in my head to text. I have a PHP app where I'm querying our database (Pervasive SQL, not MySQL so I don't have all MySQL commands available to me) and spitting the results into a JSON encoded string for use with a Google chart.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT oestats.period, oestats.salesamtf 
FROM oestats 
GROUP BY oestats.yr, oestats.period, oestats.salesamtf
```

What gets returned for salesamtf is fine with me, but period returns a numerical value for each month (e.g. 1 for January, 2 for February, etc).

I want to do two things here. I want to return January instead of 1 in my results. I'm sure that I can do this in javascript, I just assume that there must be a way to do this in the query itself or through other means? The biggest reason is my want #2:

Not only do I want to return January instead of 1, but I also want to prepend it with the year that it was grouped by in the query (e.g. 2012/January). At the moment the results are grouped correctly and I can figure out what period belongs in what year, but it takes some digging when looking at the chart.

Any ideas of how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
SELECT CASE oestats.period
WHEN 1 THEN "January, "
WHEN 2 THEN "February, "
WHEN 3 THEN "March, "
WHEN 4 THEN "April, "
WHEN 7 THEN "May, "
WHEN 6 THEN "June, "
...
ELSE "December, "
END || oestats.yr as theTimeFrame, oestats.salesamtf FROM 
oestats GROUP BY theTimeFrame,    
oestats.salesamtf
```

Can't recall if you can group by constructed fields in SQL92 or not but that should get you started.

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't working for me. I did end up altering your idea, but I still can't get it to function properly. Apparently I'm deft as I can't even get the CASE statement to work which I know exists in my version of Pervasive.SQL (10.3). All I get back are NULL values when using CASE.

Comment: Can you paste your exact modified query and I will take a look? Also start simple, just do a select case and see what comes out. Finally can you show the table definition? (if period is a char that makes a difference) you may also need to convert year to a string

Comment: Actually, I tried as a string as well. This may be a moot task as I went ahead and just did the CASE statement in my PHP code after the results were returned. What I would like to do now though is the second part of my question which is to bind the year to the period (month). e.g. 2012/5 instead of just 5 being returned. Is this even possible?

Comment: You will have to convert to a string but yes, you can concatenate fields on output (that is what the || oestats.yr does)
Did you get any output if you simply did a select for the case statement forking on period?